# What are the setup steps in deploying SQLite for an application?

Tags: .net, database, sqlite, deployment, entrypointnotfoundexcept

I am lost in trying to figure out why sqlite on my development computer works and not on another system.

I do remember I had to take number of steps before I finally got it to work on my development computer. I simply can't remember what they were.

Right now, I am testing my software on a clean system, after preparing that system for a test - like installing SQLite engine 2.5/3.5 ADO.NET. My program starts up and quits when it goes to use the database file. Window error message does show - System.Data.Sqlite and System.IO.EntryPointNotFound.

Does anybody know what that means?

Any help or hints will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are the System.Data.SQLite and SQLite.Interop DLLs located in the same folder as your application or installed in the GAC?

Comment: @sybkar, System.Data.SQLite is located in my application folder and program files/SQLite.NET/bin folder. Also, SQLite.Interop.066 dll and lib files are only located in program files/SQLite.NET/bin/compactframework/ not within my application folder. I do have reference linked to my project files for System.Data, System.Data.SQLite, System.Data.DataSetExtension.

Comment: I'd try copying the SQLite.Interop file to the application directory - I know I've gotten headaches solved this way before, though I'm not sure it was an EntryPointNotFound exception.  Where did you get the DLLs from?

Comment: @sybkar The dlls are from the SQLite-1.0.66.0-setup.exe. I am not really sure, but my problem seems to be that I have an outdated DLL(s). Do I also need to run sqlite-netFx40-setup-bundle-x86-2010-1.0.82.0.exe? I think I might have installed it too.

Comment: I'd check that you have the correct DLL versions (including 32 vs 64 bit).  They should be the same (or newer than the) version that you compiled against.  As for whether to run that other setup, that would also depend on what it was compiled with...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Sybkar. I figured out why I was having problem with SQLite on the clean system. Even though the System.Data.Sqlite dlls in my project folder was exactly the same in name and version as the dll files in the program files/SQLite.NET/bin folder, somehow they were different. Once I copied the dlls from SQLite.NET bin folder to my project folder, it worked on my clean system.

So, what you have to do is first if you are having problem similar to mine, download and install SQLite-1.0.66.0-setup.exe. Then, make sure you copy the System.Data.SQLite dlls files from SQLite.NET/Bin Folder to your project or application folder on your testing or clean system.